# Navigating a DOM hierarchy in WatiN

Tags: watin

I have a page that includes a list of lists and I'd like to navigate it with WatiN:

```
<div id="NestedLists">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Sweet</li>
                <li>Sour</li>
                <li>Salty</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Red</li>
                <li>Yellow</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know how to loop through just the *direct* decendents of an Element.  I thought this would work (note use of Lists and ListItems):

```
var treeControl = browser.Div(Find.ById("NestedLists"));
var listOfLists = treeControl.Lists.First();

Console.WriteLine("Outer List:");
foreach (var list in listOfLists.ListItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tInner List:");
    foreach(var listItem in list.ListItems)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t\tList Item: " + listItem.Text);
    }
}
```

But that gives:

```
Outer List:
    Inner List:
        List Item: Sweet 
        List Item: Sour 
        List Item: Salty 
    Inner List:
    Inner List:
    Inner List:
    Inner List:
        List Item: Red 
        List Item: Yellow 
    Inner List:
    Inner List:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is actually a tougher question than I realized, but here's a partial solution.

The ChildrenOfType function can get the direct child of some elements including Div, List and ListItem.  I've included a sample of how this works.

However, the problem with this sample is that when you display the text of a ListItem using .Text, not only is the immediate text displayed, but the text of the child elements as well.

At the very least, this sample code will provide a way to surf the list heirarchy.  You could only output the text if the listItem has no child elements, but I don't know how well that works for your situation.

```
public static void listSurfer(Div div)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Outer List:");
        var innerLists = div.ChildrenOfType<List>();
        var innerListItems = div.ChildrenOfType<ListItem>();
        if (innerListItems.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var innerlist in innerLists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List Item: " + innerlist.Text);
            }
        }
        listSurfer(innerLists, 1);
    }

    public static void listSurfer(ElementCollection<List> lstCollect, int depth)
    {
        foreach (List lst in lstCollect)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tabNumber(depth) + "innerlist");
            var innerLists = lst.ChildrenOfType<List>();
            var innerListItems = lst.ChildrenOfType<ListItem>();
            if (innerListItems.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var innerlist in innerListItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tabNumber(depth + 1) + "List Item: " + innerlist.Text);
                    var subLists = innerlist.ChildrenOfType<List>();
                    if (subLists.Count > 0)
                        listSurfer(subLists, depth + 1);
                }
            }
            if (innerLists.Count > 0)
            {
                listSurfer(innerLists, depth + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static String tabNumber(int count)
    {
        String tabs = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            tabs = tabs + "\t";
        }
        return tabs;
    }
    private static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Browser browser = new IE(@"C:\test.html");

        var treeControl = browser.Div(Find.ById("NestedLists"));
        listSurfer(treeControl);
    }
```

Comment: ChildrenOfType is just the thing I need.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since the inner lists are also part of the listOfLists the line is printed for them. A small if solves that problem:

```
                var treeControl = browser.Div(Find.ById("NestedLists"));
                var listOfLists = treeControl.Lists.First();

                Console.WriteLine("Outer List:");
                foreach (var list in listOfLists.ListItems)
                {
                    if(list.ListItems.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\tInner List:");
                    }
                    foreach (var listItem in list.ListItems)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\tList Item: " + listItem.Text);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: That certainly fixes the example.  However, I was hoping for a solution that allowed me to walk the hierarchy, so I need to just find direct descendants.   For example, if my colours list entries each had a sublist (of "shades", say), then the simple "if" fix wouldn't work (I think).